# A continuous function on $[0,1]$ not of bounded variation

Tags: calculus, continuity, examples-counterexamples, bounded-variation

I'm looking for a **continuous** function $f$ defined on the **compact** interval  $[0,1]$ which 
is **not** of **bounded variation**.

I think such function might exist. Any idea?

Of course the function $f$ such that
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $x \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$} \\\\
0 & \text{if $x \notin [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$}
\end{cases}
$$
is not of bounded variation on $[0,1]$, but it is not continuous  on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Consider any continuous function passing through the points $(\frac1{2n},\frac1n)$ and $(\frac1{2n+1},0)$, e.g. composed of linear segments. It must have infinite variation because $\sum\frac1n=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you draw an example of your function?

Comment: @OlivierOloa I'm a little tired so this will have to do: http://i.stack.imgur.com/phWFJ.png. It should be easy to imagine anyway.

Comment: It is OK! Thanks!

Comment: There is no such continuous function over the **compact** set $[0,1]$ since the construction implies that the function is unbounded.

Comment: @Muschkopp it doesn't, the construction implies the function is bounded by $1/2$.

Answer (score 13):

For example $x\sin(1/x)$ (and 0 for $x=0$).

The variation is *unbounded*, because it is *bounded* ;-) from below by the sum of absolute values of extrema, but it is the harmonic-like series.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an general idea. A function of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ is necessary differentiable a.e.. In another word, any continuous function which is not differentiable on a positive measure set is not of bounded variation. So, Weierstrass Function is not of bounded variation for sure.

Also, some function which oscillate too much can not be bounded variation as well, for example
$$ u(x)=x^a\sin(\frac{1}{x^b}) $$
is not of bounded variation as long as $1 \le a\leq b$.

Comment: Yes, with $1 < a \le b$ and $u(0)=0$, this also provides an example of a function that is differentiable everywhere but not of bounded variation.

Comment: The property about $x^a \sin(1/x^b)$ is exercise 4.4b on page 205 of Benedetto-Czaja, or exercise 35 of page 119 in Royden-Fitzpatrick. Both exercises assume $a$ and $b$ are positive. Note that if $a$ is negative then $x^a \sin(1/x^b)$ will be unbounded, so will never have bounded variation.

Answer (score 6):

The [Weierstrass Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) restricted to the interval $[0,1]$