# Creating an increasing function $g$ given a continuous function $f$, such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |g(x)-g(y)|$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Given a continuous function $f$ over an interval, must there exist a continuous, increasing function $g$ such that for all $x,y$

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |g(x)-g(y)|$$

I've tried assuming the opposite, that all $g$'s fail for some pair $x,y$ to reach a contradiction, since for every pair $x,y$, there is some $g$ that satisfies the inequality. Similarly for a finite number of pairs $x,y$ there is always a $g$ to satisfy. But I haven't gotten far with that nor used the continuity of $f$.

So I tried using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition on $f$ around a point since I might be able to connect $g$ to the values of $\varepsilon$, but I haven't found a way to do that either.

In the end, if a $g$ does exist (which I'm somewhat convinced is true), I'd like to find the "minimal" $g_0$ such that for all satisfying $g$'s and $x,y$

$$|g_0(x)-g_0(y)| \leq |g(x)-g(y)|$$

For example, $f=x^2$ and $g_0=x|x|$. Of course if there's a $g_0$, any $g_0+C$ is another one.

Thank you.

Comment: Does "increasing" here mean "strictly increasing"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, since anywhere the function is flat/constant, $g_0$ must be also.

Comment: Intuitively, draw the curve of $f$ progressively from left to right, and each time the curve goes down, you inverse the direction such that it goes up by the same scale. The the final curve you get represents the function $g$

Comment: I have a feeling that it will only be possible to find such a $g$ if $f$ is of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation).  So, for example, there might be no $g$ for $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ on an interval including $0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : You are 23 second ahead of me to answer the question...

Comment: @JohnMa well... you actually answered it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $f:[a, b]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function which is not of bounded variation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082897/a-continuous-function-on-0-1-not-of-bounded-variation) for an example. Then such a $g$ cannot be found. To see this, assume that 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le | g(x) - g(y)|$$
then by assumption, for any $M$, there is a partition $a =y_0< y_1 < y_2 < \cdots y_{n-1} < y_n  = b$ so that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n |f(y_{k}) - f(y_{k-1})| \ge M.$$

In particular,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n |g(y_{k}) - g(y_{k-1})| \ge M.$$

But $g$ is inceasing, so $g(b) \ge M + g(a)$. But $M$ is arbitrary, so $g$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: It is notable also that if such a $g$ exists, then 
$$
g(x) = V_a^x f
$$
is the "minimal" $g_0$ desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Consider the function $f : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by: $$\begin{cases}f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x} \text{ if } x \neq 0\\
f(0)=0\end{cases}$$

Considering $f$ on $[-1,0]$, what can be the value of $g(0)$?

$f$ is continuous, but it is not of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation), which forces a potential $g$ to take infinite values.