# Do there exist $f$ and $g$ continuous functions on $[1,2]$ such that $\int f dg$ does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

> Do there exist $f$ and $g$ continuous functions on $[1,2]$ such that $\int f dg$ does not exist ?

I tried with

$f(x)=1$

$g(x) = \begin{cases}
(x-1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 1 \\
0 & \text{if } x = 1
\end{cases}$

I chose $g$ which is not a bounded variation function.

Is it good example?

Another example is :

$f(x)= \begin{cases}
(x-1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 1 \\
0 & \text{if } x = 1
\end{cases}$

$g(x) = \begin{cases}
(x-1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) & \text{if } x \neq 1 \\
0 & \text{if } x = 1
\end{cases}$

but how can I prove it ?

Riemann-Stieltjes integral is really hard, so proving existence or non existence is hard.

Comment: Mahmoud, $\int_1^2\!f\mathrm dg$ exists by using the functions you chose, indeed in the first case it results that $$\int_1^2\!\!f\,\mathrm dg=\int_1^2\!\!1\,\mathrm dg=g(2)\!-\!g(1)=g(2)=\sin1\;\;,$$whereas in the second case ,$$\int_1^2\!\!f\,\mathrm dg=\int_1^2\!\!g\,\mathrm dg=\frac12\left[g(2)^2\!-\!g(1)^2\right]=\frac12g(2)^2=\frac12\sin^2\!1\,.$$

Comment: Is g differentiable at $1$? I recall that it isn't differentiable at $1$

Comment: Sorry, it exists but not continuous at $1$

Comment: If you know a continuous function that is not of bounded variation on $[1,2]$, then isn't the integral $\int_1^2 1dg$ (i.e. the choice $f=1$) not defined? You may only need one such function, then.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer    But doesn't $g'$ exists and continuous on $(1,2)$ and so 
$\int fdg = \int fg' dx$?  (g is not of bounded variation)

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar If $g$ is not of bounded variation, then there is no possibility of $g'$ existing and being continuous on $(1,2)$. For example, read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082897/a-continuous-function-on-0-1-not-of-bounded-variation) and change any such function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ to $g :[1,2] \to \mathbb R$ by setting $g(x)=f(x-1)$. Then, $\int_1^2 1 dg$ won't exist.